# bash read between two strings using parameter expansion expression

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

This is how my input string looks like:

```
INPUT_STRING="{/p1/p2=grabthistext}"
```

I want to print `grabthistext` from the `INPUT_STRING`.

I tried `echo "${INPUT_STRING##*=}"` which prints `grabthistext}`

How do I read only `grabthistext` using parameter expansion expression?

Comment: `echo "${INPUT_STRING#*{}%}"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want a single parameter expansion then you can use:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob

INPUT_STRING="{/p1/p2=grabthistext}"

echo "${INPUT_STRING//@(*=|\})}"
```

```
grabthistext
```

---

I would use a bash regex though:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_STRING="{/p1/p2=grabthistext}"

[[ $INPUT_STRING =~ =(.*)} ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

```
grabthistext
```

Answer (score 2):

```
temp="${INPUT_STRING##*=}" 
echo "${temp%\}}"
grabthistext
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two steps: first extract the fragment after `=` as you already did, and store it in a new variable. Then use the same technique to remove the undesired `}` suffix:

```bash
INPUT_STRING="{/p1/p2=grabthistext}"
TEMP_STRING=${INPUT_STRING##*=}
OUTPUT_STRING=${TEMP_STRING%\}}

echo "$OUTPUT_STRING"
# grabthistext
```

Check it [online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/39MvIDQkPjgkyNPP3VapWr/AUL/AyDa9KDGpJCOzuCS1oqRWiSvE1TcApkalGlmLsrKWbS2Xf2gIkikq1UjqVWNqa7m4UpMz8hWUVFDUKXH9/w8A).